# Regression analysis with binary independent (categorical) variables and continous dependent variable

Tags: regression, categorical-data, model-selection, binary-data, nonlinear-regression

I am working on a dataset with 14 binary (0 or 1) independent variables (product features) and trying to measure a continous dependent variable (product price). I tried doing a regression analysis to predict my dependent variable based on the independent variables. I tried the following ways -

1. I checked for multicollinearity and dropped the predictors with a high variance inflation factor (VIF).
2. None of the 14 features seem to have a linear relationship with the dependent variable, as my individual features have values of only 0 and 1.
3. None of the 14 features has $p$-value $< 0.05$ when I print the regression results.
4. I tried both linear and polynomial regression, but there is no major improvement in the $R^{2}$ value.

How are such situations handled? Please shed some light on any suggested approaches.

Comment: Welcome. How did you go about including a quadratic term(s) with all binary inputs? Could you provide more detail?

Comment: Using sklearn I imported PolynomialFeatures, I ran a function to loop my independent variables to the degree in range of 2 to 5, and got the best degree = 4 for one of my independent variable. I went ahead and raised the degree to 4 for this variable and ran the model to fit on my training set , but it did not result any better results

Comment: "None of the 14 features seem to have a linear relationship with the dependent variable, as my individual features have values of only 0 and 1." I am not sure what this means. Your slopes are all 0 or 1? This is not the way you test for linearity normally. You would look at the residuals or conduct a box tidwel test or both.